# Translate firewall rule from iptables to nftables

Tags: iptables, nftables

I have this rule for `iptables`

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -i eth0 -p tcp -s 192.168.178.20 --dport 8201 -j REJECT
```

I was looking for *how to translate rules* tutorials but couldn't find them.
How do I create that rule with `nftables`? Or is the syntax the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From nftables [wiki](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Moving_from_iptables_to_nftables):

> Since June 2018, the old xtables/setsockopt tools are considered legacy. However, there is support to use the iptables/ip6tables/arptables/ebtables old syntax with the nf_tables kernel backend. This is described with further details in the Legacy xtables tools wiki page.

You can use `iptables-nft` to achieve your goal like below:

```bash
iptables-nft -I INPUT 1 -i eth0 -p tcp -s 192.168.178.20 --dport 8201 -j REJECT
```

After that entering, `iptabels-nft-save` will apply your rules. You can confirm that this rule exists in nftables by:

```bash
nft list ruleset
```

You have to see something like this:

```bash
nft list ruleset                 
table ip filter {
        chain INPUT {
                type filter hook input priority filter; policy accept;
                iifname "eth0" ip saddr 192.168.178.20 tcp dport 8201 counter packets 0 bytes 0 reject
        }
}
```

In addition you can directly translate your rules using the below syntax:

```bash
iptables-translate -I INPUT 1 -i eth0 -p tcp -s 192.168.178.20 --dport 8201 -j REJECT
```

which will give you the following output:

```bash
nft insert rule ip filter INPUT iifname "eth0" ip saddr 192.168.178.20 tcp dport 8201 counter reject
```

Also, you can just save all of your iptables rules like `iptables-save > save.txt` and then use `iptables-restore-translate -f save.txt` to get the translated rules.

Take a look at my own [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/1108207/how-to-avoid-ip-mac-spoofing-and-block-desired-ports-for-qemu-kvm-virtual-mach/1108366#1108366) a few months back for further explanation.